# pandas how to apply pairwise function between each two rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a datafame:

```
df = A.  B.  C.  D. 
     1.  2.  3.  4
     1.  2.  3.  5
     8.  1.  6.  5
     1.  2.  4.  3
```

And I want to apply a function between each combination of two rows into a new matrix, such that in the cell (i,j) I will have the value of applying the function on rows #i and #j.
So if my function is `scipy.stats.pearsonr` , in location (0,0) I will get 1, and the value of (0,1) is `pearsonr([1,2,3,4] , [1,2,3,5])[0] = 0.98`.

What is the best way to do so?

Comment: Use df.corr with pearsonr

Comment: @Dani this is `corr` happy hour ;)

Comment: @DaniMesejo, maybe `df.T.corr()`

Comment: @mozway 1) My df is 15905 X 27. When I run corr I get a mat of 27X27 (each row and col is a feature) . Is should get 15905X15905 (each row and col is a sample)
2) pearsonr is just an example can u please add a code for a custom func?

Comment: I think you need to do what @d.b said do the transpose, .corr has a method parameter that you can use and pass a callable